# Creality Ender 5 Pro stops working

Tags: creality-ender-5

I bought the Creality Ender 5 Pro 29th of December 2021, so it's pretty new.
I have done about a hundred prints by now, without any problems, it's a damn good workhorse... until last Friday.

The printer stopped after making the brim, just full stop, the board didn't respond so I had to turn the printer off and on. I tried to resume the print but it stopped working right away, after that I turned it off and on again, and send it to auto home, that just works fine. Restarted the same but new print, and everything stopped working at the same spot again. Turned on some other prints, same thing stopped working after the brim.

At this point, I decided to check out the hotend, filament, etc. I couldn't do much with the hotend as the nozzle was fully stuck, unable to remove, so I bought a full new hotend set. It didn't solve the problem, even with the new hotend it stops after printing the brim. So I tried different slicers, again, no difference. Cura/Creality/Prusa slicers, nothing works.

I tried changing the settings of the prints, but nothing worked either.
I did notice that the printer stops at the same point, which is almost right in the middle of the bed.
I have a new bed, a PEI bed, which is not deformed it has no bumps.
I did not do anything with the programming, I also did not change the motherboard. The bed is perfectly level. The filament doesn't seem to be a problem either after using up 3 kilos already without problems.

So to remove some things that ain't the problem:

- the bed is not the problem
- slicer program is not the problem
- hotend is not the problem
- bed level is not the problem

So there are 2 things left (what I know about).

- the SD card
- motherboard/software

If anybody knows what the problem might be, or what else I can do to fix it, please let me know. I'm starting to run out of ideas that I myself can fix.

The prints I have tried are different models (STL file) and different slicers are used.
I made a new model, a simple 2 cm by 2 cm by 3 mm square, it stops after the brim.
I tried the prefab dog model that is on the SD card, without a brim, and it stops around the same time/spot, the only difference is that it keeps pushing out filament which does not happen with the self-made models.
I also found out that it happens at all places, there is no difference in printing in the left corner, or in the middle of the bed.
I unplugged all the cables and connectors and reconnected them again, I removed the hotend and attached it again, so that it is perfectly lined up.

A video of the problem: https://www.loom.com/share/d58e7e1db719480f81b765e83988e9e4?fbclid=IwAR2GT0MA2VtEO7TpB2jx9Km5Kf4sJkD5W3CYHjAgFbf51fGrWaoGm-_9MSU

Comment: It actually doesn't stop after the brim, it stops during the first layer of the object. Please provide a link to your source G-code e.g. using PasteBin. It is a long shot considering you used different slicers.

Comment: Hey, have you solved this problem yet?

Answer (score -3):

To fix the Ender 3 not printing or starting, you need to reflash the firmware to rule out any errors, calibrate your hot end temperature with PID Tuning, and check your filament if it has snapped from somewhere. The Ender 3 also won't print if the nozzle is too close to the print bed or the nozzle has been clogged.

Comment: Please note that the question is about an Ender 5, not 3. Firmware shouldn't be a problem, the printer worked for hundreds of prints.